# How to start SSH Server in my Android?

Tags: ssh

I am trying to login to Android Eee pad transformer from my other linux box using SSH. This are the step i followed and failed. So asking here for the correct answer.

1) Go to Android market and download install Connectbot

- Launching ConnectBot
- Asks ssh or telnet or local
- Press local
- Asks username
- Username applied dummy
- Connected to local Android
- type ip addr; in the terminal
  shows ip address and i can ping 8.8.8.8

[image]

2) Now i want to access to this box from outside box

- Go to Android market and install SSDroid and SuperUser
- Launch SSDroid
- SSDroid says root:off, sftp://root@ipOfthisAndroidBox:2222 ready
- From another box i try to login using ssh root@ipOfthisAndroidBox:2222 fails

[image]

3) Launch SuperUser it tries to install something but fails

[image]

All i get to verify am i rooted, always it shows:

```
$ su
su: permission denied
```

**Follow up:** How do i login after installing SSHDroid?

```
[sun@example ~]$ ssh root@94.xx.xx.xx -p 2222
The authenticity of host '[94.xx.xx.xx]:2222 ([94.xx.xx.xx]:2222)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 14:ae:33:xxxx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[94.xx.xx.xx]:2222' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
SSHDroid
Use 'root' on rooted devices otherwise any username works
Default password is 'admin'
root@94.xx.xx.xx's password: 
/data/data/berserker.android.apps.sshdroid/home $ uname -a
Linux localhost 2.6.36.3-00004-g069b8b5 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed May 11 22:14:22 CST 2011 armv7l GNU/Linux
/data/data/berserker.android.apps.sshdroid/home $ uptime
 09:20:16 up 2 min, load average: 0.26, 0.25, 0.11

/ $ ls
EeePad_bootup_first_page.rle  acct                          default.prop                  init.ventana.rc               sys
OSD_battery_100.rle           bin                           dev                           mnt                           system
OSD_battery_25.rle            cache                         etc                           proc                          ueventd.goldfish.rc
OSD_battery_50.rle            config                        init                          root                          ueventd.rc
OSD_battery_75.rle            d                             init.goldfish.rc              sbin                          ueventd.ventana.rc
Removable                     data                          init.rc                       sdcard                        vendor

 More informations: https://gist.github.com/1357588
```

How do i login to my Android box from other distro's? (I am using Fedora, CentOS, FreeBSD).

Comment: "From other box when i try to login, i cant" isn't enough information.  What exactly are you doing from the other box?  Have you confirmed that you can ping the phone from the box?  Have you investigated SSHDroid's settings?

Comment: if you can't "su" you dont have root access to the device. sshdroid says that root is not required

Comment: @MatthewRead 1) I installed ConnectBot. And then i did ip addr to see my ip. From my other box i can ping that IP. But i can not do ssh@androidbox. 2) Then i installed SSHDroid, it says sftp://root@thisip:2222 ready 3) once i try that from  other box, i also still can not login. 4) i then using ConnectBot tried to su ...; su; su -; sudo; sudo -s; sudo -; but all says "permission denied". How do i solve this? So that i can login from outside to inside Android.

Comment: @Ryan Conrad: How do i then get root access? SSDroid if says root is not required. Then why can i not login from outside using $ ssh username@androidip:port

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[SSHDroid](https://market.android.com/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sshdroid) does not need root, it's optional. Every App can bind a socket on an not privileged port (>1024).

**I am pretty sure that your `ssh` client parameters are wrong, the port especially.  AFAIK you can't add the port via `:` to the hostname. Try `ssh root@ipofandroid -p 2222` instead.**

If you need more verbose output of the `ssh` binary, start it with `-v`, `-vv` or `-vvv`. This helps to figure out problems.

Comment: Step by step guide: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34040560/895245

Answer (score 3):

Your android box running SSHDroid, just activate it.

Your Linux Box (GUI) you can run any SSH FTP compliance (Nautilus, Filezilla, etc...)
For ex. I use FileZilla ... just type

1. on host : sftp://your.android.box.ip-address
2. on user name : root
3. on password : admin
4. on port : 2222

Just select "OK" button whatever appears on your screen.

Note : you must on the same subnet mask and class for it to happen ..